# allowing nested contigious match in regex

Tags: regex

My data is:

```
Hello
Test1
Begin
* nm: 866 444 988
* nm: 08 66
# allowed * nm: 77 2
End
* nm: 0
```

i want capture each digit between markers `Begin` and `End` and must be preceded by

```
* num: or # allowed * nm:
```

My pattern work well in .Net (i use capture collection) but it not work in other engine ...my question is how **can add another ancher \G** to capture nested contigious digits: ( the question is about mastering the \G anchor)

```
(?mxi:
  \G(?!\A)(?:^# allowed[ ])?
   |
  ^Begin\r\n
 )
 \*[ ]nm:[ ]
 (?>(?'digit'\d+)|[ ])+ # the problem is here it return all digits in one group
 \r\n
```

It return each digit in capture value

Thanks

Edit:
I found a solution but its not an élégant pattern:

```
(?mx:
   \G(?!\A)
      |
   ^Begin\r?\n
)
(?:#[ ]allowed[ ])?
\*[ ]nm:
  |
(?!^)\G[ ]*(\d+)\s*
```

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/80Ih6QGb9J)

Edit: 2)

Another problèm with my second pattern: if i add `[ ]*\r?\n` instead of \s* in the end of  the pattern it fail. Why?

```
 (?xm:
     \G(?!\A)
         |
     ^Begin\r?\n
 )
 (?:#[ ]allowed[ ])?
 \*[ ]nm:
     |
 (?!^)\G[ ]*(\d+)
 [ ]*\r?\n # <-- the problem here
```

Comment: Do you really have to do it in 1 pass only?

Comment: @anubhava: yes my question is about nested \G anchor and contigious digit match...thanks

Comment: what platform? is it perl compatible?

Comment: generally speaking, my opinion is do not try to do that in a row. since the more restrictions you place in a regex, the slower the matching is and the harder for others to understand it.

Comment: Your final solution also matches `123` at the start, possibly forgot to put `(?!\A)` before the last `\G`

Comment: @Jonny5: Thank you i add (?!^) before last \G and it work but it's not elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern: *(Java/PCRE/Perl/.NET version)*

```
(?xm)  # switch on freespacing mode and multiline mode*
(?: \G(?!\A) | ^Begin\r?$ )  # two entry points: the end of the last match OR
                             # "Begin" that starts and ends a line

(?> \n  # a newline can start with:
    (?:
        (?:\Q# allowed \E)? \Q* nm:\E  # 1) the start of a line with numbers,
      |
        (?=End\r?$)                    # 2) the last line end of a block,
      |
        .*                             # 3) or an other full line
    )  
)*  # this group is optional to allow several consecutive numbers,
    # but the branch 3) can be repeated several times until the branch 1)
    # matches and the first number is found, or until the branch 2) matches
    # and closes the block.
\Q \E      # a space
(\d+)  \r? # the number
```

<sub>(*) be careful with the multiline mode and Ruby: *In other languages the multiline mode changes the meaning of `^` and `$` anchors from "start of the string" and "end of the string" to "start of the line" and "end of the line". In Ruby the multiline mode allows the dot to match newlines (an equivalent of "singleline" or "dotall" mode for other languages). In Ruby `^` and `$` matches the start and end of line by default whatever the mode.*</sub>

This only uses the fact that numbers are not a the start of a line.

When the regex engine takes the branch 2) of the alternation the pattern will automatically fail since `(?=End$)` can not be followed by `\Q \E (\d+)`. Since the newline and three branches are enclosed in an atomic group, the regex engine has no possibilities to backtrack and to try the branch 3). In this way, the contiguity is broken, each time the branch 2) matches.

**Notices:**
The `\Q...\E` feature allows to write a literal string without escaping special characters. In freespacing mode, all spaces inside `\Q...\E` are taken in account.

To make this pattern work with ruby, you need to remove the m modifier, to remove all `\Q` and `\E` and to escape or enclose in a character class all spaces, special characters and the sharp used in freespacing to write a comment.
 Example: `(?:\Q# allowed \E)? \Q* nm:\E` => `(?:\#[ ]allowed[ ])? \*[ ]nm:`

Comment: There is a lot of little caveats specific to the structure that probably he's not aware of. I was thinking about doing that `(?=End$)` as part of an atomic group but wanted to keep it a little general.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: thanks but i tested your pattern in rubular (ruby engine) and regexstorm (.Net engine 'with simple modification') and in php but not work: https://eval.in/195285

Comment: Worked in a Perl engine I tested with.

Comment: @walidtoumi: the pattern is written for Java (without double escape) and works with PCRE too. You can see a demo here: http://fiddle.re/9b4bm (click on Java)

Comment: @walidtoumi: it works with ruby too if you don't use the `\Q...\E` syntax that is not supported: http://rubular.com/r/YsH159wbjn

Comment: I think that version of php on eval.in might have a problem with atomic groups.

Comment: @sln: why? atomic groups are fully supported with php (PCRE).

Comment: That's what I thought. Must be something else. More likely that website has poor support for php. I tried all the variations on that site, couldn't get it to work. Used `[ ]*` padding, nothing worked, but it kind of points to their implementation of php.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: sorry my mustake and yes it works..thanks..can you please comment your pattern

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: thank you your code work in most flavor but it not work in .NET (i try in regexstorm.net)                   `(?m:\G(?!\A)|^Begin$)(?>\r?\n(?:(?:# allowed )?\* nm:|(?=End$)|.*))* (\d+)` why ?

Comment: @walidtoumi: indeed, its a mistake about the CR character and the `$` anchor. `(?:\G(?!\A)|^Begin\r?$)(?>\n(?:(?:# allowed )?\* nm:|(?=^End\r?$)|.*))* (\d+)\r?`

Comment: @walidtoumi: note that you can't put the m modifier here `(?m:\G...` otherwise the scope of the modifier will be only this non capturing group and not the whole pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The number is in group 1 on each match. It won't be a capture collection, but that's why `\G`
is there anyway. Also, due to the nature of this, it just invalidates the match position when
`end` is found.

**edit** - Note that you could put a capture group around `(Begin)` as a flag for the start of a new block.

```
 # (?mi:(?!\A)\G|(?:(?:^Begin|(?!\A)\G)(?s:(?!^End).)*?(?:^(?:\#[ ]+allowed[ ]+)?\*[ ]+nm:)))[ ]+(\d+)

 (?xmi:
      (?! \A )
      \G 
   |  
      (?:
           (?:
                ^ Begin  
             |  
                (?! \A )
                \G 
           )
           (?s:
                (?! ^ End )
                . 
           )*?
           (?:
                ^ 
                (?: \# [ ]+ allowed [ ]+ )?
                \* [ ]+ nm: 
           )
      )
 )
 [ ]+  
 ( \d+ )                            # (1)
```

With extra comments:

```
 (?xmi:
      (?! \A )                # Here, matched before, give '[ ]+\d+` a first chance
      \G                      # to match again.
   |  
      (?:                     # Here, could have matched before
           (?:
                ^ Begin                 # Give a new begin position first chance
             |                        # or,
                (?! \A )                # See if this matched before
                \G 
           )

           # If this is new begin or matched before, move the position up to
           # the first/next delimiter 'nm:'

           (?s:                    # Lazy, move the position along (dot-all in this cluster)
                (?! ^ End )
                . 
           )*?
           (?:                     # Here we found the first/next delimiter
                ^ 
                (?: \# [ ]+ allowed [ ]+ )?
                \* [ ]+ nm: 
           )
      )
 )
 [ ]+  
 ( \d+ )                 # (1)
```

Comment: Thanks it work. Could you explain your pattern..espicially the part into the two non capturing group

Comment: I tested your code in rubular and it work but in regexstorm.net (.NET engine) but it not return all digits. Is there a way to make your code 'universal' or in most flavour

Comment: I don't think `Dot-Net` engine has the `\G` anchor construct. Why would it need it when its got capture collections. Want me to show how its done in Dot-NEt?

Comment: Dot-net support \G anchor.. my first pattern work well in .NET but it's not universal because i use captureCollection object..your pattern return only first digits..you can try with regexstorm.net

Comment: Ok, if Dot-Net supports \G, you have to find first, then do find next in a loop (changing the start position each time). The behavior is the same with \G, it only matches once per find. If in Dot-Net you happen to do `(?: [ ]+ (\d+) )+` it will be a capture collection per line. But this is not transferable to other engines that don't support it. Other engines overwrite the capture group each quantified pass. (btw, I use VS2010 for my tests.)